# How to yield inside an included template with laravel?

Tags: php, laravel

With Blade it seems the `yield` does not work with included parts. How can I fill a section defined inside an included part in the parent template?

It seems this is a known issue: 
https://github.com/laravel/framework/issues/8970

### template-body.blade.php

```
<body>
@yield('body')
<body>
```

### template-html.blade.php

```
<html>
@include('template-body')
@yield('other')
</html>
```

### foo.blade.php

```
@extends('template-html')
@section('body')
Hello World! (does not work)
@endsection
@section('other')
Does work
@endsection
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

what you are doing will give you an error. you can include pages on the template and other sub pages. it just depends on what you are doing and how you doing it. what you should have done is:

```
//app.layout
 <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>@yield('title')</title>
<your-css-files>
@yield('styles')
<your-script files>
@yield('scripts')
</head>
<body>
@include('your page')
@yield('content')

</body>
</html>
```

then on your pages you do:

```
@extends(app.layout)
@section('content')
<h1>This is a Heading</h1>
<p>This is a paragraph.</p>
@include('your page')
@endsection

on the samepage you can call your styles and scripts as

@section('styles')
 //css files
@stop

@section('scripts')
 // javascript files
@stop
```

Comment: What I would like to do is declare a section inside « your page » and yield some content

Comment: i dont think its proper because its ends up duplicating the information on the main layout